# Run GTK+ application in client browser

Tags: gtk, web-applications

I've been searching for ways to run a GTK+ application on a browser.

WebKit and its associated GTK+ port seem to do the opposite - making applications more Web-friendly, but the opposite would also be nice.

There seems to have been some activity to realize that for XCode, with Cappuccino and Atlas, that can translate NIB files into CIB files.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that GTK+ 3.2 will include features allowing you to expose your desktop app as a web app. Check out [1]: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/gtk-32-will-let-you-run-any-application.html

Answer (score 2):

The WebKit port is just a port of the [WebKit browser engine](http://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk) to use GTK+ API:s whenever possible. So, instead of using pthreads directly to create a thread, it uses [GThread](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html) and so on.

What you're asking is completely different, not "the opposite".

Actually, it isn't very clear what you're asking. Do you want the browser (client-side) to execute the GTK+ application code, and somehow magically transform the interface into web controls? That seems extremely difficult, my answer would be "no, that is not possible".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, what you said about the WebKit is what I understand.

I would like to add a layer on top of existing GTK+ applications to enable it to be run as a Web application, or at least export data to a port for a web browser to connect to and display it on the client side. Sort of like a application-specific VNC if you will.

Not sure if that explains it better?